# Move background on click event jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="menu1">item 1</li>
  <li id="menu2">item 2</li>
  <li id="menu3">item 3</li>
</ul>

<div id="arrow">&nbsp;</div>
```

The list has the CSS setting: `display: inline` and under the active menu item is an arrow that points to the active menu item.

The default CSS setting for the arrow is:

```
#arrow {
  background: url('./arrow-up.png') no-repeat 10px 0;
}
```

Which places the arrow under `item 1` by default.

I created the following jQuery code but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens when I click a link and the arrow doesn't move.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#menu1").click(function(){
      $("#arrow").animate({
          background: url('./arrow-up.png') no-repeat 10px 0
      }, 1500 );
  });

  $("#menu2").click(function(){
      $("#arrow").animate({
          background: url('./arrow-up.png') no-repeat 90px 0
      }, 1500 );
  });

  $("#menu3").click(function(){
      $("#arrow").animate({
          background: url('./arrow-up.png') no-repeat 180px 0
      }, 1500 );
  });
});
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use this plugin: http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/

```
$('#menu1').click(function(){
    $('#arrow')
        .animate({backgroundPosition:'10px 0'});
});
```

Comment: It wasn't working. I changed it and now it works. (Sorry for editing your post but I didn't want to steal your accepted answer tick ;-) )